# Write image metadata to JPG/PNG file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, metadata

Is there any way to write a UIImage to a JPG/PNG file and then append metadata to it?  I know you can use:

writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock

to do this in the Saved Photos, but how do you do the same thing directly to a file?  I can't seem to find any way to do this.  I know that UIImagePNGRepresentation() and UIImageJPGRepresentation() will give you NSData that you can use to write the file, but there's no way to append/replace the metadata in the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this answer to a similar question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125323/problem-setting-exif-data-for-an-image/5294574#5294574

Comment: Writing a custom PNG exporter is a matter of 3 days, anyway :)

Comment: You should take a look at ImageIO framework for that. You can add metadata to `CGImageDestination` using `CGImageDestinationSetProperties` and then get the raw data from it

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432411/email-jpg-created-in-app-including-metadata).

To add metadata to a UIImage you can use the ImageIO framework You can create a CGImageDestination object from a UIImage, add metadata to it using CGImageDestinationSetProperties and then get the raw data (which includes the compressed image and the metadata) from it.

Answer (score -7):

@rekle 
Check it out this code is for writing  the photo in to file

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);
            NSData *myImage=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:imageData];
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);

            NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",camtitle.text]];
            [myImage writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"%@",fullPathToFile);
            [myImage release
```

];

Comment: This does not address the question of how to add metadata to the file