# How does one add custom metadata tags to an image on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, metadata, exif

I tried adding custom entries in the exif dictionaries I received from an image. This didn't work. I'm assuming this is due to the fact exif is a standard that is already defined.

Basically I am trying to create a metadata tag that can be placed in jpegs that will have no character limit.

I read that XMP metadata tags do not have character limits. Is this true? If so how would I create these on the iPhone?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with objective-c in an app your building? I am trying to understand the method in which you want to add the metadata to an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you've all tried code wise, but [Caffeinated Cocoa](http://caffeinatedcocoa.com/blog/?p=7) has a pretty good blog entry on Image Metadata that I've used in an application for a client a while ago that might help you.

Also, the SO post [Problem setting exif data for an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125323/problem-setting-exif-data-for-an-image) looks like it references the Caffeinated Cocoa.  Although this question is a little over a year old, it still might help.

Try giving these a shot.