# Custom metadata tags on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image, metadata

There is a similar question few years ago was asked in this thread [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567240/how-does-one-add-custom-metadata-tags-to-an-image-on-the-iphone). Unfortunately no answer was given. I know how to read and write defined EXIF, TIFF, etc. tags on iOS (kCGImageProperty* tags). The problem is Apple for some reason ignored many useful meta tags which I need in my app. Is there any way to "register" missing tags using standard iOS libraries, such that adding them to dictionary would end up in the meta-header of an image?

Comment: Goto `CGImageProperties.h` and look for all the properties you can use in iOS.

Comment: That wasn't the question. I know which properties are available. The one that I need are not there. The question was - can I add those that are missed somehow. Problem with Image I/O it uses string constants and not real tag values, so if I define a new constant it won't be translated into EXIF tag

Comment: I understood what you are asking, but I wanted to say you can't. Rather if you want any extra information you can use `kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment`