# Write UIImage along with metadata (EXIF, GPS, TIFF) in iPhone's Photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exif, alassetslibrary

I am developing a project, where the requirements are:
- User will open the camera through the application
- Upon capturing an Image, some data will be appended to the captured image's metadata.
    I have gone through some of the forums. I tried to code this logic. I guess, I have reached to the point, but something is missing as I am not able to see the metadata that I am appending to the image.
    My code is:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)dictionary 
{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSData *dataOfImageFromGallery = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image,0.5);
    NSLog(@"Image length:  %d", [dataOfImageFromGallery length]);


    CGImageSourceRef source;
    source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)dataOfImageFromGallery, NULL);

    NSDictionary *metadata = (NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);

    NSMutableDictionary *metadataAsMutable = [[metadata mutableCopy]autorelease];
    [metadata release];

    NSMutableDictionary *EXIFDictionary = [[[metadataAsMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy]autorelease];
    NSMutableDictionary *GPSDictionary = [[[metadataAsMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary]mutableCopy]autorelease];


    if(!EXIFDictionary) 
    {
        //if the image does not have an EXIF dictionary (not all images do), then create one for us to use
        EXIFDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    if(!GPSDictionary) 
    {
        GPSDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    //Setup GPS dict - 
    //I am appending my custom data just to test the logic……..

    [GPSDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];
    [GPSDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.2] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];
    [GPSDictionary setValue:@"lat_ref" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];
    [GPSDictionary setValue:@"lon_ref" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];
    [GPSDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.3] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSAltitude];
    [GPSDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithShort:4.4] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSAltitudeRef]; 
    [GPSDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.5] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSImgDirection];
    [GPSDictionary setValue:@"_headingRef" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSImgDirectionRef];

    [EXIFDictionary setValue:@"xml_user_comment" forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
    //add our modified EXIF data back into the image’s metadata
    [metadataAsMutable setObject:EXIFDictionary forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
    [metadataAsMutable setObject:GPSDictionary forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];

    CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(source);
    NSMutableData *dest_data = [NSMutableData data];

    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef) dest_data, UTI, 1, NULL);

    if(!destination)
    {
        NSLog(@"--------- Could not create image destination---------");
    }


    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, (CFDictionaryRef) metadataAsMutable);

    BOOL success = NO;
    success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);

    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"-------- could not create data from image destination----------");
    }

    UIImage * image1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dest_data];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image1, self, nil, nil);    
}
```

Kindly, help me to do this and get something positive.
Look at the last line, am I saving the image with my metadata in it?
The image is getting saved at that point, but the metadata that I am appending to it, is not getting saved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function: `UIImageWriteToSavePhotosAlbum`  only writes the image data.

You need to read up on the [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary)

The method you ultimately want to call is:

```
 ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]
 [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock];
```

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated in iOS9. [PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit?language=objc) is where it's at now.

Answer (score 13):

Apple has updated their article addressing this issue (Technical Q&A QA1622). If you're using an older version of Xcode, you may still have the article that says, more or less, tough luck, you can't do this without low-level parsing of the image data.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1622/_index.html

I adapted the code there as follows:

```
- (void) saveImage:(UIImage *)imageToSave withInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Get the assets library
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    // Get the image metadata (EXIF & TIFF)
    NSMutableDictionary * imageMetadata = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] mutableCopy];

    // add GPS data
    CLLocation * loc = <•••>; // need a location here
    if ( loc ) {
        [imageMetadata setObject:[self gpsDictionaryForLocation:loc] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
    }

    ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock imageWriteCompletionBlock =
    ^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"Wrote image %@ with metadata %@ to Photo Library",newURL,imageMetadata);
        }
    };

    // Save the new image to the Camera Roll
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imageToSave CGImage] 
                                 metadata:imageMetadata 
                          completionBlock:imageWriteCompletionBlock];
    [imageMetadata release];
    [library release];
}
```

and I call this from

```
imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
```

which is the delegate method for the image picker.

I use a helper method (adapted from [GusUtils](https://github.com/gpambrozio/GusUtils)) to build a GPS metadata dictionary from a location:

```
- (NSDictionary *) gpsDictionaryForLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    CLLocationDegrees exifLatitude  = location.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees exifLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

    NSString * latRef;
    NSString * longRef;
    if (exifLatitude < 0.0) {
        exifLatitude = exifLatitude * -1.0f;
        latRef = @"S";
    } else {
        latRef = @"N";
    }

    if (exifLongitude < 0.0) {
        exifLongitude = exifLongitude * -1.0f;
        longRef = @"W";
    } else {
        longRef = @"E";
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *locDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [locDict setObject:location.timestamp forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSTimeStamp];
    [locDict setObject:latRef forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];
    [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exifLatitude] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];
    [locDict setObject:longRef forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];
    [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exifLongitude] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];
    [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.horizontalAccuracy] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDOP];
    [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.altitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSAltitude];

    return [locDict autorelease];

}
```

So far this is working well for me on iOS4 and iOS5 devices.

**Update**: and iOS6/iOS7 devices. I built a simple project using this code:

https://github.com/5teev/MetaPhotoSave

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who comes here trying to take a photo with the camera in your app and saving the image file to the camera roll with GPS metadata, I have a **Swift solution** that uses the [Photos API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos) since **[ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/reference/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary) is deprecated as of iOS 9.0**.

As mentioned by rickster on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665119/6431067), the Photos API does **not** embed location data directly into a JPG image file even if you set the .location property of the new asset.

Given a CMSampleBuffer sample buffer `buffer`, some CLLocation `location`, and using Morty’s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967345/6431067) to use `CMSetAttachments` in order to avoid duplicating the image, we can do the following. The `gpsMetadata` method extending CLLocation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nitrag/343fe13f01bb0ef3692f2ae2dfe33e86).

```
if let location = location {
    // Get the existing metadata dictionary (if there is one)
    var metaDict = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(nil, buffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate) as? Dictionary<String, Any> ?? [:]

    // Append the GPS metadata to the existing metadata
    metaDict[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String] = location.gpsMetadata()

    // Save the new metadata back to the buffer without duplicating any data
    CMSetAttachments(buffer, metaDict as CFDictionary, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
}

// Get JPG image Data from the buffer
guard let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer) else {
    // There was a problem; handle it here
}

// Now save this image to the Camera Roll (will save with GPS metadata embedded in the file)
self.savePhoto(withData: imageData, completion: completion)
```

The `savePhoto` method is below. Note that the handy `addResource:with:data:options` method is available only in iOS 9. If you are supporting an earlier iOS and want to use the Photos API, then you must make a temporary file and then create an asset from the file at that URL if you want to have the GPS metadata properly embedded (`PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage:atFileURL`). Only setting PHAsset’s .location will NOT embed your new metadata into the actual file itself.

```
func savePhoto(withData data: Data, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    // Note that using the Photos API .location property on a request does NOT embed GPS metadata into the image file itself
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
      if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        // For iOS 9+ we can skip the temporary file step and write the image data from the buffer directly to an asset
        let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
        request.addResource(with: PHAssetResourceType.photo, data: data, options: nil)
        request.creationDate = Date()
      } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions; write a temporary file and then add this file to the Camera Roll using the Photos API
        let tmpURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("tempPhoto").appendingPathExtension("jpg")
        do {
          try data.write(to: tmpURL)

          let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: tmpURL)
          request?.creationDate = Date()
        } catch {
          // Error writing the data; photo is not appended to the camera roll
        }
      }
    }, completionHandler: { _ in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion?()
      }
    })
  }
```

Aside:
If you are just wanting to save the image with GPS metadata to your temporary files or documents (as opposed to the camera roll/photo library), you can skip using the Photos API and directly write the imageData to a URL.

```
// Write photo to temporary files with the GPS metadata embedded in the file
let tmpURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("tempPhoto").appendingPathExtension("jpg")
do {
    try data.write(to: tmpURL)

    // Do more work here...
} catch {
    // Error writing the data; handle it here
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but how do I get a CMSampleBuffer from a UIImage?

Comment: @Chris In my case, I set up a var for an `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`, from which we can get an AVCaptureConnection (`.connection(withMediaType:`). Then the completion block of `captureStillImageAsynchronously(from:)` has a `CMSampleBuffer?` and an Error. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492339/swift-3-photo-capturing for some sample code.

Comment: The `location` argument seems not to be used in the `savePhoto` function.

Comment: This is very nice but it doesn't answer the question. We are not starting from a sample buffer but from a UIImagePickerController that has just taken a picture.

Comment: @matt I suggested `AVFoundation` because it's great for complex file processing and allows more camera customization. `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`’s `captureStillImageAsynchronously` produces the sample buffer.
 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348398/avcapturesession-vs-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819958/avcapturesession-vs-uiimagepickercontroller-speeds) list advantages of `AVFoundation` over `UIImagePickerController`. Neither of the two requirements OP gave explicitly state a `UIImagePickerController` must be used.

Comment: The very first line of his code is `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:` , and he says what he's starting with is a UIImage, so I presume that is where we need to do this. Anyway, that's what I was looking for a solution to when I encountered your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Getting meta data from cam captured image within an application:

```
UIImage *pTakenImage= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]];
```

now to save image to library with extracted metadata:

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[sourceImage CGImage] metadata:imageMetadata completionBlock:Nil];
[library release];
```

or want to save to local directory

```
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destinationPath,sourceImage,0, (CFDictionaryRef)imageMetadata);
```

Comment: What would be the solution with PHPhotoLibrary, because ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated since iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem we are trying to solve is: the user has just taken a picture with the UIImagePickerController camera. What we get is a UIImage. How do we fold metadata into that UIImage as we save it into the camera roll (photo library), now that we don't have the AssetsLibrary framework?

The answer (as far as I can make out) is: use the ImageIO framework. Extract the JPEG data from the UIImage, use it as a source and write it and the metadata dictionary into the destination, and save the destination data as a PHAsset into the camera roll.

In this example, `im` is the UIImage and `meta` is the metadata dictionary:

```
let jpeg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(im, 1)!
let src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(jpeg as CFData, nil)!
let data = NSMutableData()
let uti = CGImageSourceGetType(src)!
let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data as CFMutableData, uti, 1, nil)!
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(dest, src, 0, meta)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest)
let lib = PHPhotoLibrary.shared()
lib.performChanges({
    let req = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
    req.addResource(with: .photo, data: data as Data, options: nil)
})
```

A good way to test — and a common use case — is to receive the photo metadata from the UIImagePickerController delegate `info` dictionary thru the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` key and fold it into the PHAsset as we save it into the photo library.

Comment: How to store rotation (orientation) of the image in EXIF format?

Comment: I used some parts of your code to write a more complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634582/529663

Answer (score 1):

There are many frameworks that deals with image and metadata.

Assets Framework is deprecated, and replaced by Photos Library framework. If you implemented `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` to capture photos, you can do so:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    var metadata = photo.metadata
    metadata[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String] = gpsMetadata
    photoData = photo.fileDataRepresentation(withReplacementMetadata: metadata,
      replacementEmbeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat: photo.embeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat,
      replacementEmbeddedThumbnailPixelBuffer: nil,
      replacementDepthData: photo.depthData)
    ...
}
```

The metadata is a dictionary of dictionaries, and you have to refer to [CGImageProperties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties).

I wrote about this topic [here](https://samwize.com/2018/05/17/photos-app-and-exif-location-data/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight variation of @matt answer.

The following code use only one CGImageDestination and more interesting allow to save in HEIC format on iOS11+.

Notice that the compression quality is added to the metadata before adding the image. 0.8 is roughly the compression quality of native camera save.

```
//img is the UIImage and metadata the metadata received from the picker
NSMutableDictionary *meta_plus = metadata.mutableCopy;
//with CGimage, one can set compression quality in metadata
meta_plus[(NSString *)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality] = @(0.8);
NSMutableData *img_data = [NSMutableData new];
NSString *type;
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) type = AVFileTypeHEIC;
else type = @"public.jpeg";
CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)img_data, (__bridge CFStringRef)type, 1, nil);
CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, img.CGImage, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)meta_plus);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
CFRelease(dest); //image is in img_data
//go for the PHLibrary change request
```