# Swift 3 photo capturing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using this piece of code:

```
func capturePhoto(blockCompletion: @escaping blockCompletionCapturePhoto) {
    guard let connectionVideo  = self.stillCameraOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
        blockCompletion(nil, nil)
        return
    }

    connectionVideo.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.orientationFromUIDeviceOrientation(orientation: UIDevice.current.orientation)

    self.stillCameraOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connectionVideo) { (sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, err: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let err = err {
            blockCompletion(image: nil, error: err)
        }
        else {
            if let sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer) {
                let image = UIImage(data: dataImage)
                blockCompletion(image: image, error: nil)
            }
            else {
                blockCompletion(image: nil, error: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It worked fine in Swift 2.0, but after conversion it's not working anymore.
This line:

```
self.stillCameraOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connectionVideo) { (sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, err: NSError!) -> Void in
```

is giving me the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(CMSampleBuffer!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((CMSampleBuffer?, Error?) -> Void)!'

I've already tried some things but can't get it solved. 
Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: I think that `NSError` got renamed to `Error` in Swift 3. Simply remove `NS` and it should be fine. Did you migrate your code? It'd be strange if it didn't catch that.

Answer (score 3):

What the error

> Cannot convert value of type '(CMSampleBuffer!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((CMSampleBuffer?, Error?) -> Void)!'

basically says is that your argument is of the wrong type (`(CMSampleBuffer!, NSError!) -> Void`) while it should be of the type  `((CMSampleBuffer?, Error?) -> Void)!`.

To achieve this, try using this code, it should automatically make your block conform to the right type:

```
self.stillCameraOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connectionVideo) { sampleBuffer, error in
    //do stuff with your sample buffer, don't forget to handle errors
}
```

It looks like a weird type but I think it's a little error Apple made somewhere while migrating this code from ObjC to Swift 1 to Swift 2 to Swift 3.

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work, let me know if it actually did!

Comment: I can confirm that this solves the compilation error in Swift 3

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3 that command changed!

from:

```
captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection
```

to:

```
captureStillImageAsynchronously
```

so try this code:

```
self.stillCameraOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: connectionVideo, completionHandler: {
         (sampleBuffer, error) in
  // do your stuff here
}
```