# Convert NSData to UIImage with metadata (EXIF data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

My `NSData` which contains an image taken from an external hardware has metadata.. I have tested it by uploading the image to AWS.

I have tried these two conversions:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:_downloadedImageData ];

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:_downloadedImageData];
```

I have done my research and found out whenever `NSData` is converted to `UIImage` or vice versa the metadata (EXIF data) is lost. How do I convert such that my meta exits in both conversion i.e `NSData` to `UIImage` and vice versa

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

create path to save the image data.

```
NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                   NSUserDomainMask,
                                                   YES);
NSString *path = [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0]
              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"_downloadedImageData.data" ];
```

retrieving the saved data

```
NSData *retrievedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];
[self.view addSubview:img];
```

Comment: nope it doesn't work.. i tried all combinations of : 
    [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"_downloadedImageData.data" ];
     [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"_downloadedImageData" ];
    [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloadedImageData.data" ];
    [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloadedImageData" ];

Comment: @NithinReddyGaddam Please follow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965299/write-uiimage-along-with-metadata-exif-gps-tiff-in-iphones-photo-library)