# Custom Overlay UIImagePickerController Landscape mode issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

I have a `UIImagePickerController` with custom overlay. When I open the camera in landscape orientation in  `iPhone`, the camera view is not displayed properly. I don't want the camera view in landscape mode. I want the camera view only to be opened in portrait mode.

[image]

Can someone pls help me out on this?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484816/force-uiimagepickercontroller-to-take-photo-in-portrait-orientation-dimensions-i