# How to attach metadata to UIImage without saving to library

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, camera, uiimage

I have a function capturing few images and add them into `NSMutableArray` **rawImages** of `UIImage`. Then I pass this **rawImages** to other object to apply some image processing on the images in the array. In the image processing, I need to retrieve the *exposure time* from EXIF metadata.

I have been able to get the EXIF from `CMSampleBuffer` when capturing using `AVFoundation`. Is there a way to attach this EXIF to the **rawImages** array?
(PS: I know that one can save it into library and then read the images from library along with the metadata, but I don't want that)

Any help is much appreciated! THANKS!

Comment: Follow [this url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125323/problem-setting-exif-data-for-an-image). It adds metadata *without* saving to library.

Comment: @tipycalFlow thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for. If I got it right, the url you gave solves problem of modifying image metadata; whereas I don't need any modification, I am just looking for a way to attach this metadata along with the UIImage (if any)

Comment: Are you asking for something like a custom `Image` object that contains the `UIImage` AND the metadata as its members (so that you can control the attached data)?

Comment: @tipycalFlow yes, something like that. Does that exist?

Comment: It's not available from Apple or any 3rd party lib I'm aware of but you could easily create your own by subclassing `UIImage` and adding the required properties