# Save Exif data to Image inside Documents folder on iOS device

Tags: ios, exif

I have UIImage *photoImage containing jpg file. I would like to add EXIF data to this image like UserComment, ImageDescription and Software.  I would like to save this file to Documents folder on my iOS device as myImage.jpg I don't want to save it to PhotoLibrary.

I am not sure how to add EXIF data.

I would save image to disk by using

```
NSData *photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImage, 1);
[photoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

How do I add EXIF data to photoData? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this very closely related question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125323/problem-setting-exif-data-for-an-image)

Comment: Yes I have. It is referring to iOS 4.1 and it is fairly complicated. I was wondering if there is something simpler and easier to comprehend. If I would like to save photo to PhotoLibrary I would be able to use just one line of code `[assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[photoImage CGImage] metadata:dict completionBlock:nil];`