# Saving an Image using Parse SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

**Taking Image:**

I'm taking the image using the code in this question:
[Scaling UIImage with a UIIImagePicker's CGAffineTransform and Saving to Parse SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769310/scaling-uiimage-with-a-uiiimagepickers-cgaffinetransform)

**Convert UIImage to NSData & Save**

```
    _imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image, .1);
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:_imageData];
    newMessage[@"image"] = imageFile;
```

**Problem:**

When I redownload the data, the UIImage appears squished. When I look at the image on my database, it seems like the height and width are reversed. Not sure why this is happening...

Comment: What's your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];

    PFObject *userPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [userPhoto setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];

    // Set the access control list to current user for security purposes
    userPhoto.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [userPhoto setObject:user forKey:@"user"];

    [userPhoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"sucess");
        }
        else{
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        [[ConnectionManager sharedManager] removeload];
    }];
```