# Updating an in-memory iOS UIImage with EXIF/geotag information

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, exif

I am trying to update a `UIImage` with geotag information.  I looked at [Saving Geotag info with photo on iOS4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884060/saving-geotag-info-with-photo-on-ios4-1), which is where I found a reference to the [NSMutableDDictionary+ImageMetadata category](https://github.com/gpambrozio/GusUtils/blob/master/GusUtils/NSMutableDictionary+ImageMetadata.m).  However, I don't want to save to the photo album, but have a `UIImage` to pass on.

The following code seemed like it was making too many copies of the image and required all these frameworks linked: CoreImage, AssetsLibrary, CoreMedia, ImageIO.

Is there something more efficient that `UIImage` -> `CIImage` -> `CGImage` -> `UIImage` that can take the properties NSDictionary needed for setting EXIF data?

```
- (UIImage *)updateImage:(UIImage *)image location:(CLLocation *)location dateOriginal:(NSDate *)dateOriginal
{
    NSMutableDictionary *properties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[image.CIImage properties]];

    // uses https://github.com/gpambrozio/GusUtils   
    [properties setLocation:location];
    [properties setDateOriginal:dateOriginal];

    CIImage *tempImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image options:properties];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];    
    UIImage *updatedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:tempImage fromRect:tempImage.extent]];

    return updatedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at libexif: http://libexif.sourceforge.net/

You'll probably need to pass the image's byte data to the library using

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, quality) bytes]
```