# Disappearing Thumbnails

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, assetslibrary

In my application I've noticed the images I'm saving are begin written to a photo album and display properly in the Photos application.  However, when I removed the image from which the new image was copied, the new image's thumbnail disappears.  It's really strange.

Here's the code I use to create a CGImageRef to save to the assets library:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary
    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge NSNumber *)kCFBooleanTrue,
            (__bridge NSString *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways, nil];
CGImageRef fullImage = [asset.defaultRepresentation CGImageWithOptions:options];
```

Before I was just grabbing the defaultRepresentation.fullResolution image and writing it to the assets library.

My question is:  By saving the image this way, is the thumbnail I expect being created?  And, if not, should I do something different to get my thumbnails to be created so they don't "disappear".

EDIT:
The error in the console when this occurs is:

```
Aug 18 11:08:27 [phone name] [app name][2081] <Error>: Fixing thumbnail for 0x112b2dc0 <x-coredata://97C87589-EC35-4664-BE0D-AD01687EF7C4/Asset/p3637> AF6CD736-EF5D-482A-AFAD-F12834C301BF at index 2
```

The failed thumbnail repair seems occurs only for images where I'm modifying the GPS dictionary with new coordinates.  Images where I remove the coordinates have the thumbnails repaired correctly.

Here's my code for that section:

```
NSDictionary *gpsDictionary =
    [readOnlyMetadata valueForKey:(__bridge NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *modifiableGpsDictionary = (gpsDictionary) ?
    [gpsDictionary mutableCopy] : [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = thumbnail.coordinate;

[modifiableGpsDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:ABS(coordinate.latitude)]
    forKey:(__bridge NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];
[modifiableGpsDictionary setValue:(coordinate.latitude < 0.0) ? @"S" : @"N"
    forKey:(__bridge NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];
[modifiableGpsDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:ABS(coordinate.longitude)]
    forKey:(__bridge NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];
[modifiableGpsDictionary setValue:(coordinate.longitude < 0.0) ? @"W" : @"E"
    forKey:(__bridge NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];

[modifiableMetadata setValue:modifiableGpsDictionary
    forKey:(__bridge NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the way I was adding GPS data to images without an existing dictionary is the problem:

[Saving Geotag info with photo on iOS4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884060/saving-geotag-info-with-photo-on-ios4-1)