# Download Image with AFHTTP and save it to ALAsset

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, afhttpclient

Does anyone know how to save an image to the Asset Library? I know that saving it to the Asset, the image will be available also in the Gallery of the iPad.

I know how to get the file:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:downloadRequest];

[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

// How to make the filepath? 
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
[operation.responseData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write an image into the assets library, you can use any of the three methods below (defined in class `ALAssetsLibrary`):

```
– writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:
– writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:
– writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:
```

This requires that your image is either represented as a `UIImage`, a `CGImageRef` or a `NSData` object.

For example, you might save your image using a `NSOutputStream` associated to a temporary file. Then, create and initialize a `UIImage` with that file and write it into the assets library using the above method.

Alternatively, load the image as a NSData object (if it fits nicely into memory) and again use the appropriate method above, along with meta information.

See also: [ALAssetsLibrary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Edit:**

If you want to get more information about how to setup the metadata parameter, you may find this blog post valuable: [Adding metadata to iOS images the easy way](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/05/11/adding-metadata-to-ios-images-the-easy-way/).

And if you want to add Geolocations to your image metadata on SO: [Saving Geotag info with photo on iOS4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884060/saving-geotag-info-with-photo-on-ios4-1)

Comment: Good question ;)  The AV Foundation is more specific about "metadata", but in AL it's quite obscure. You may take a look into sample file "SquareCamViewController.m" in the Apple sample "SquareCam" and try to deduce some conclusion what it *might* be.

Comment: Uhm, it should be clear that the meta data of an image is commonly known as "EXIF" data (Exchangeable Image file Format). But I don't know how to setup the keys and values for the Dictionary representing the metadata. See also wiki article about EXIF: [Exchangeable image file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format)

Comment: Ah, after digging for "EXIF" in the Apple docs, you may find valuable info for "EXIF Dictionary Keys" in  "CGImageProperties Reference".